# Difference between statements inside and outside accept block

Tags: ada

Suppose the following (server) task specification:

```
task type Server_Task is
      entry E1(I: Integer);
      entry E2;
      entry E3;
end Server_Task;
```

with a (dummy) implementation of:

```
task body Server_Task is      
   begin
      loop
         select
            accept E1(I: Integer) do
               -- statements inside E1 using I
               -- statements inside E1 using I
               -- statements inside E1 using I
               null;
            end;                       
         or
            accept E2 do
               null;               
            end;
         or
            accept E3 do
               null;
            end; 
         end select;         
      end loop;     
end Server_Task;
```

Based on my understanding, if a client task makes an entry call for (say) E1 then *all* statements inside the `E1` accept block will be executed before the server task loops over again and is ready to accept another entry call. The same is true if there are further statements following the `end` of the accept block so that again *all* these will need to run before the task can randevouz with a calling task again.
If that assumption is correct, I'm wondering what the behavioural difference is between the above implementation and the one below:

```
task body Server_Task is
      Temp: Integer;
   begin
      loop
         select
            accept E1(I: Integer) do
               Temp := I;       
            end;
            -- statements outside E1 using Temp
            -- statements outside E1 using Temp
            -- statements outside E1 using Temp
         or
            accept E2 do
               null;               
            end;
         or
            accept E3 do
               null;
            end; 
         end select;         
      end loop;     
end Server_Task;
```

Will there be a difference if the statements *outside* `E1` make a blocking call and hence the server task is suspended and therefore these statements will then have to somehow compete with any other entry calls made by the task's clients? (though this doesn't make much sense if the task is implemented using just one "thread"?)

For the sake of argument suppose the client code is along the lines of:

```
ST: Server_Task;   
   task body Client_Task is
   begin
      select
         ST.E2;
      else
         -- do something else
         null;
      end select;
      null;
   end Client_Task;
```

Is this behaviour detailed somewhere in the ARM? - Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so there's several language features in play here... perhaps the best way to explain how things are working is with evolving a small "protocol" -- first let's have a system that accepts one `A`, two `B`s, and a `C`:

```
Task Example_1 is
   Entry A;
   Entry B;
   Entry C;
End Example_1;

Task Body Example_1 is
Begin
   -- Protocol accept one A, followed by 2 B, finished with a C.
   Accept A;
   Accept B;
   Accept B;
   Accept C;
End Example_1;
```

Excellent, there we have a task that receives messages `A`, `B`, `B`, `C`, in order and terminates. Now, complexifying the protocol a bit, let's make the protocol `A`, followed by either a `B` or a `C`, then terminated with an `A`.

```
Task Example_2 is
   Entry A;
   Entry B;
   Entry C;
End Example_2;

Task Body Example_2 is
Begin
   -- Protocol: A, (B or C), A.
   Accept A;
   Select
      Accept B;
   or
      Accept C;
   End Select;
   Accept A;
End Example_2;
```

Now to complexify things a bit more: let's say that the task is a parser and `A` is submission of text, `B` is retrieval of token(s) and the length of unused text, and `C` is returning unused text, all in a loop until Finished:

```
Task Example_3 is
   Entry A(Text : in     String);
   Entry B(List :    out Token_List; Remainder :    out Natural);
   Entry C(Text :    out String);
   Entry Finish;
End Example_3;

Task Body Example_3 is
  Temp     : String_Holder.Holder:= String_Holder.Empty_Holder;
  Result   : Token_List:= Empty_List;
  Finished : Boolean:= False;
Begin
  Parser_Loop:
  Loop
   -- Protocol: Loop of (A, B, C) or finished.
   Select
     Accept A(Text : in     String) do
       Temp:= To_Holder( Text )
     End A;
     -- Processing TEMP here.
     Accept B(List :    out Token_List; Remainder :    Out Natural) do
        List := Result;
        Remainder:= Temp.Element'Length;
     End B;
     Accept C(Text :    out String) do
        Text:= Temp.Element;
     End C;
   or
     Accept Finish do
       Finished:= True;
     End Finish;
   End Select;
   Exit Parser_Loop when Finished;
 End loop Parser_Loop;
End Example_3;
```

And there to have most of the basics in understanding `entry`, `accept` and `select` -- the only other important thing to remember is that the things in an `ACCEPT` between `DO` and `END` are the rendezvous, and thus both the caller and callee are synchronized... if you want the parallelism increases, be sure to do your actual processing *outside* the rendezvous.

Comment: Thank you for that, with the help of your small protocol I think I now get the difference..so, following through the protocol, a client can initially make a `A` call and then as soon as the randevouz ends (i.e. after `End A;`) it can go off and do other stuff whilst the server task is executing the`-- Processing TEMP here.` statements.

Comment: Then, following the protocol it can call the `B` entry and from there, there are two possibilities: a) the server task has finished executing the "outside" statements, has looped-over and is blocked waiting for an entry call, in which case the client will randevouz immediately _or_ b) the server task hasn't finished with the "outside" statements in which case the client task blocks waiting for its entry call to be accepted.

Comment: If, however, all statements were _inside_ the `accept` block then a client wouldn't be able to run any other stuff in parallel with the processing of the server task as it would be (b)locked inside the randevouz..this of course assumes that the client _does_ run additional logic prior to calling the `B` entry as if it didn't it wouldn't probably make any difference whether the statements are inside or outside the `accept` block.

Comment: Also, in order for this parallelism to work an important assumption, I think, is that this application is running on a multi-core system as again on a single-core it wouldn't probably make much difference whether the statements are inside or outside the `accept` block.

Comment: @Sidisyom - You have most of it, except for the single-/multi-core system issue. The great advantage of `Task` is that it allows abstraction of the low-level details, so that (e.g.) the whole "*we have to rewrite everything to take advantage of multicore!*" several years ago would be solved simply by recompiling on a multicore-aware compiler. .. or, in more modern settings, instead of trying to tune for 2/4/6/8 cores or some particular number (looking at you, CUDA) you simply write in the logical breakdown you would use anyway.

Comment: yeah, good point, that would be a more future-proof and parallel-ready implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The big difference is that both the server and the client are locked into waiting on that accept statement to complete before moving on.  You are correct that in both cases the server is still running the same code essentially regardless of position.  But in the first case, the client is waiting there for those statements to complete while in the second case the client can move on and do other stuff while those statements after the accept go.

There are pros/cons to both scenarios.  In the first, you have the capability of doing operations that are protected from data races for the client, while in the second case, if those statements adjust global/shared data then you open yourself up to data races since both client and server can operate on that data.

That said, I prefer the 2nd scenario for most cases, only falling back to the 1st when I need to protect data.  The main reason is it frees up the client to do other work instead of waiting.

```
        accept E1(I: Integer) do
           -- statements inside E1 using I
           -- statements inside E1 using I
           -- statements inside E1 using I
           null;
        end;  -- Client is free
```

vs

```
        accept E1(I: Integer) do
           null;
        end;  
        -- Client is free everything after is potentially unsafe 
        -- for client, but the client can do other things quicker
        -- statements inside E1 using I
        -- statements inside E1 using I
        -- statements inside E1 using I
```

For your third part:
That select is basically only checking for the Rendezvous to start.  Once the rendevous starts, you are in there as far as the client is concerned.  The "else" part only applies while waiting for the rendezvous to even occur.

For blocking statements "after" the rendezvous, those will delay or prevent the next rendezvous from occuring until they resolve.  They won't affect the client directly unless it is making another rendezvous to the same task later or to a protected object entry that both tasks share.  At that point though, your "ELSE" in the select statement will be chosen since the client can't re-enter the rendezvous until the server finishes the blocking tasks and gets back to the accept statement code.

All of this is detailed in the arm.  I don't know the sections offhand, but look for the tasking section in the table of contents or look up select statement in the index.

Comment: hmm..so, from the client's perspective, it can wait for ever, make a timed call and wait for a bit for the randevouz to take place or it can make a conditional call and not wait at all (have updated the question with a dummy implementation of the 3rd case). A bit confused as to why it matters whether the server is executing those statements inside or outside the accept block..i.e. in that specific case won't the client run the `else` statements _immediately_ as the server won't be able to accept the `E2` call in either case?

Comment: @Sidisyom I updated my answer for your last part.  Basically that version of the select statement is only checking for the rendezvous to be ready (both tasks are able to enter).   Sorry, I don't know the arm sections specifically.  It is detailed there

Comment: @Sidisyom why it matters inside/outside is again, if inside, then both tasks are stuck in that rendevous until it completes and if it is a blocking call both tasks are there.  In reference to the select statement added later, that only applies before and "up until" the rendezvous starts.  Once it starts, the client is in there with the server until the "end" of your "accept do" is reached.

Comment: if the statements are outside, then the client can go do other things while those block only for the server.  But if the client does try to do the rendezvous again while those are blocking it will wait (or hit the ELSE in your select if using that method) for that new rendezvous

Comment: thank you for that, sorry I'm probably missing something but I still don't get it :)

Comment: Suppose two client tasks `T1`&`T2` and a server task `TS` and the following scenarios:

Comment: *Scenario#1* (all statements inside the accept block): `T1` makes an entry call for `E1`, `ST` accepts that call and starts executing the statements. Whilst it's doing that `T2` makes a call for `E2` but since it can't randevouz immediately as `ST` is inside the accept block, it branches straight away to the `else` part.

Comment: *Scenario#2* (one statement inside the accept block and the rest outside): `T1` makes an entry call for `E1`, `ST` accepts the call and executes the accept block. Then it (`ST`) goes outside the accept block and starts executing the statements following that. Whilst it's doing that `T2` makes an entry call for `E2` but again since it can't randevouz immediately it branches straight away to the `else` part.

Comment: So just wondering, would that be an accurate assumption of the interplay between all three tasks?

Comment: (assume the same course of events would take place if the `E2` call was a timed one rather than conditional? i.e. in scenario#2 the timeout would have to be greater than the total duration of _both_ the accept statement and the ones outside, in order for the call not to be aborted?)

Comment: @Sidisyom It depends on how you update your timeout (current time + duration vs static duration).  For the first you would want the timeout to cover everything.  For the other you would only need to cover the statements outside the accept block + time it takes to get back around to the accept block again in the loop.  You might consider making this part a separate new question

Comment: ok great, many thanks for all the input @Jere